# Dynamic column insertion with twitter bootstrap layout

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to show elements in a responsive structure based in 4 columns like this:

```
+------------------------ row ------------------------+

[--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--]

+------------------------ row ------------------------+

[--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--]
```

So I proceed to iterate the items:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($items as $i): ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <?php echo $i->getName(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The code above will work for 4 items or less because twitter bootstrap grid systems (I think so) is based on 12 cols per row. I want to avoid this:

```
+------------------------ row ------------------------+

[--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] 
[--col-*-3--] ...

+------------------------ row ------------------------+

[--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--] [--col-*-3--]
```

So, some people could say "*chunk the array or use a flag to track if row  is fill*". But I want to avoid these operations in the html file. My question is, how can I deal with this design keeping `four columns` structure without broke responsive layout? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this will break your layout.
Your solution should work, i've tried something similar.
Maybe it's the .col-lg that breaks your solution for the smaller screen?
Here an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vkNRpnckcD2JhTzAr9A7?p=preview) with .col-xs.
Do you try to specify the width of the col for every screen resolution?

```
 ...
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3"> 
 ...
</div>
 ...
```